# what is the best way to get the base URL from a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Inside my controller how would i get the base URL.

for example, if my url is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/MyController/MyAction
```

I want to have a function that returns :

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

Comment: Do you care about the port  `http://www.mysite.com:8000/MyController/MyAction`?

Comment: How do you get this URL? is it the request URL?

Comment: @ErikPhilips do you have any soludion that will give `http:// mysite.com : 8000`

Comment: @Smith you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method i use in my c# application

```
 public static string base_url()
 {
  return string.Format("{0}://{1}/", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
 }
```

Take note that this returns the port also if your development server is using another port other than 80