# How to get base url of the site in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to send an email to the user where he can click on link to transfer to my site. I don't want to hard code the url in my Email Templates. I want this dynamic in a sense that whatever the environment it will send the related url. Like If I am on the development environment it send something like `http://localhost:port` or in production send the actual website url. `http://www.domain.com`

I just need to know how can I save it in `DynamicViewBag` in MVC Action. Any suggestion plz?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638962/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-base-url-from-a-controller

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var dynamicViewBag = new DynamicViewBag();
dynamicViewBag.AddValue("BaseUrl", Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
```

Comment: How can I set this in DynamicViewBag?

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you pleas also let me know, how do I access it in view? By the way I marked your suggestion as answer because this is what I really asked in the question. Wondering if you please help me to access it in view

Answer (score 18):

You can use the properties of the Request object, for example

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request
var address = string.Format("{0}://{1}", request.Url.Scheme, request.Url.Authority);
```